# XSLT - include value from XML in HTML Table Header

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm learning XSLT using a simple example that has XML records in this format:

```
<cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS Records</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1988</year>
</cd>
```

The following XSLT is working well to return all records in the XML as an HTML table:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th style="text-align:left">Title</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Artist</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I've now been asked to include the value of the country field from the first XML record in the Title header (the country will have the same value for all records).

I've tried the following but it's not working:

```
<th style="text-align:left">Title <xsl:value-of select="country"/></th>
```

I've never to had to retrieve a value from the XML out of the "for-each" loop before so not sure what the correct syntax for this is or if it's even possible?

Comment: Your XML sample does not match your XSLT: it has no `catalog` wrapper.

Comment: I only included a snipped of the XML, but it does include the <catalog> wrapper. Sorry for the omission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="catalog/cd[1]/country"/>
```